# Custom business objects in vue

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am new to vue and have a few questions around using a simple business object in my vue single page components.  Let's stay I have an object called ResultCalculator.  This is a simple javascript class that contains my core business logic for calculating something.  Now assume I want to use this object in my Home.vue component.  My questions are:

1) Is it best practice to simply create a new file called ResultCalculator.js and

```
export default class ResultCalculator {...}
```

2) In order to import this into Home.vue I use the import ResultCalculator from `'....ResultCalculator.js'`

3) In my create method, I simply new up a new object and assign it to `this.resultCalculator`.

The above is working for me, but is it best practice?

4) Now I'd like to reference some data in vuex state store.  I doesn't seem like I simply use `this.$store.getter`. How do I reference vuex in this component?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code snippets so we have a better idea of what you have/want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just create a js file and import it to your .vue files there is nothing wrong with that.

You can not use `this.$store` because in ResultCalculator.js `this` is not vue. You can either pass `this.$store` as an argument or just simply import your store to ResultCalculator.js